# What's it called when you unfairly wrong someone just because you don't like them?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example: if a teacher marks a students work down just because they don't like the student. Or if a McDonald's worker only fills your coffee cup half way because they remember the last time when you complained about your chips being cold.

I'm not even sure there is a word for the way that person is behaving - 'Stop being so _____?'.

I want to say jealous/revenge/karma/awkward/mean but those words just don't seem to fit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe also [_unprofessional_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unprofessional?q=unprofessional) as we expect people to perform their duties according to the standards set forth or the terms of the bargain, whatever their feelings might be for a customer.

Comment: Persecution perhaps?

Comment: A useful word in this context is "biased". One may be biased for or against someone or something. If a teacher marks a student down because they don't like the student one might say that the the teacher is biased against or prejudiced against the student.

Comment: @martin: "Stop being so persecution"??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit or "Stop persecuting me!" ...

Comment: They don't sell chips at McDonalds.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: They do if you are a BrE speaker.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I know, but does McDonalds actually advertise them as chips in the UK?

Comment: Just another day at SO :D (pun intended).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*...because they remember the last time...*

out of [**grudge**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grudge)

> A persistent feeling of ill will or resentment resulting from a past insult or injury:
>
> *I’ve never been one to hold a grudge*

<sub>EDIT: As JR points out, 'out of grudge' isn't a very common phrase. (A paltry 1500 hits on [Google books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22out%20of%20grudge%22&tbm=bks))</sub>

---

*... just because they don't like the student...*

out of [**spite**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spite)

> A desire to hurt, annoy, or offend someone:
>
> *he’d think I was saying it out of spite*

---

> Stop being so **spiteful**

Comment: Of course! My brain is very fuzzy today so thank you for your help, my thesaurus wasn't quite cutting it.

Comment: @IanFerguson: You're welcome :)

Comment: @TusharRaj, I knew it would be you. +1.

Comment: To verbify *grudge*, consider *begrudge*.

Comment: It's worth pointing out: while _out of spite_ is a common phrase, _out of grudge_ is [not](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+spite%2C+out+of+grudge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @J.R.: Good catch. ['Because of a grudge'](https://goo.gl/1YgP4e) seems slightly more idiomatic, but 'out of grudge' is not totally [unheard-of](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22out+of+grudge%22&tbm=bks). I've always wondered why do we say 'I hold **a** grudge'; but never 'I hold seventeen grudges'

Comment: @talrnu: `begrudge` is a synonym of the verb `grudge`, which is _not_ the verb form of the noun `grudge`. It has a different meaning,

Comment: @TusharRaj I was thinking of the form of *begrudge* which means "to hold a grudge against someone for owning or enjoying something you don't have". I forgot about the form you're talking about, which means "to give (something) unwillingly", similar as you say to the verb grudge which means "to be unwilling to give (something)". I also didn't realize the form of *begrudge* I intended was limited to envy, e.g. I thought you could begrudge someone for their actions or ideals (out of disdain, not envy), but apparently I've been wrong.

Answer (score 19):

**Resentful**

feeling or expressing bitterness or indignation at having been treated unfairly.

**Indignant**

feeling or showing anger or annoyance at what is perceived as unfair treatment.

**Vindictive**/**vengeful**

having or showing a strong or unreasoning desire for revenge.

Comment: +1, good suggestions, would you care to link some resources!!!

Comment: I'm getting loads of good words here, and a really helpful community thanks :)

Comment: @MystiSinha: Thanks! I don't know what you call the results that Google yields when you google 'Define [something]'. It's not a website, it's just a short paragraph containing the definition.(Oh God! This is making me feel very stupid)

Comment: @IanFerguson: My pleasure!

Comment: @AishwaryaAR: Google's primary source of definition is Oxford. It moves on to others if Oxford doesn't define it. Go [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/define), right click on the search-box and click 'add as search engine'. You can now search Oxford directly from Chrome's omnibox.

Comment: +1 "vindictive" really is the word the querent is after.

Comment: "vindictive/vengeance" was my answer.

Comment: 'Vindictive' was the first thing that came to my mind. It implies malicious intent, which seems to be key to what you're trying to express.

Answer (score 8):

**[Petty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/petty)** or **[mean-spirited](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mean-spirited?s=t)** also work here, if the offense is relatively minor (a police officer planting drugs on a suspect because she didn't like his T-shirt slogan would not be petty- it would be criminal).

Answer (score 6):

When your negative feelings affect your treatment of someone, it is often called "***prejudicial*** treatment". The opposite of this would be "*preferential* treatment".

Answer (score 1):

This question admits of more than one answer.

If you are unfair, or do harm to someone just because you don't like them (the teacher example), you can be "**morally evil**", "**unjust**", "**foul**", "**spiteful**", or a dozen synonyms depending on what you've done.

If you don't like the person because of a minor incident, you are the kind of person who **nurses a grievance** or **holds a grudge** (as already mentioned by Tushar).

But for something more serious, and you want **to get even**, I would say it's revenge. And you may be a **revengeful** person.

> - evil (adj)  morally bad, causing harm or injury to someone [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evil)
> - revengeful - (adj)  "full of or prone to revenge" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revengeful)
> - grievance - (noun) " a feeling of resentment or injustice at having been unfairly treated" e.g. In the petition, the students listed their many grievances against the university administration. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grievance)
> - get even (verb) informal, "if you get even with someone who has done something bad to you, you do something bad to them" [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+even)
> - grudge -  (noun) " A persistent feeling of ill will or resentment resulting from a past insult or injury"  e.g. She held a grudge against her former boss. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/grudge)

Comment: That is true, I suppose it depends on the severity of what action is being performed in order to achieve 'revenge'. I went with 'out of spite' in the end as i guess you could say the person was being rather petty about the issue. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: Typo: This question *allows more* than one answer. (no "of")

Comment: To say a teacher is **morally evil** if he or she gives a C (or 7) for an assignment, is a bit extreme!

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Have I written that, Mari-Lou?   There is a comma after "teacher" and several adjectives depending on what harm is inflicted.

Comment: Unless they give you a C instead of an A because you're ginger - that's morally evil! haha

Comment: @Mari-LouA   Admit of - To allow the possibility of something: This problem admits of two very different solutions {TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/admit+of)

Comment: You're right! But I would never have said that "admit of" as it is used in your sentence was permissible. But apparently it is. I learnt something new today.

Comment: As for the teacher, you write "teacher example" in brackets, *immediately* after "If you are unfair, or do harm to someone just because you don't like them", so, yes, you have written that a teacher can be called "morally evil" if they have harmed or been unfair to someone they have disliked. I prefer "unfair".

Comment: +1 for "more than one answer"

Answer (score 1):

No good answer here, but for possible inspiration: you are looking for the inverse of "nepotism" or "favoritism".  Sadly, searching for opposites of these will mostly yield results tending towards fairness, rather than unfairness in the opposite direction.

Technically it *is* a form/side of favouritism or nepotism, but those might not convey your meaning very well in context.

Answer (score 0):

To *snub* someone, *spurn* them, *scorn* them, etc. is to perform an act or gesture of disdainful rejection toward them.

When you perform a gesture or action to insult someone, it could be said you are *thumbing your nose* at them. There is a litany of similar idioms.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently used for this is **hateful**.

> arousing, deserving of, or filled with hatred.
>
> "hateful letters of abuse that had come unsigned"